# What is the structure of a node for this B-Tree specification?

Tags: structure, nodes, b-tree

I am trying to create a B-tree with the following properties:

Every node x contains following attributes:

1. x.n is the number of keys present in node x
2. x.key1,x.key2,.....x.keyx.n are the keys present in the node
3. x.c1,x.c2,.........x.cx.n,x.cx.n+1 are the pointers to the child nodes
4. x.leaf is a boolean variable that shows whether the node is a leaf node or not

Based on this specification, how would I implement the structure for a node:

```
struct  Node{
    ...?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The notional structure when drawn is something like this.

```
        a      b      c      d
      /     |      |      |     \
     la     bab    bbc    bcd   gd

     la  = less than a
     bab = between a and b
     bbc = between b and c
     bcd = between c and d
     gd  = greater than d
```

Where there are more pointers than elements.

So a b-tree of order N has at most N children.  So using `BTREE_ORDER` as this value, and ensuring `BTREE_ORDER` is greater than 1.

The structure is most efficiently done as

```
struct Node{
    size_t numNodes;
    KEY_TYPE Key[BTREE_ORDER -1];
    struct Node * Children[BTREE_ORDER];
}
```

So it has space for `BTREE_ORDER-1` keys and `BTREE_ORDER` child nodes.  The arangement is up to the code, and is

```
Children[0] Key[0] Children[1] Key[1] .... Key[numNodes - 2] Children[ numNodes - 1]
```

Comment: Suppose b-tree has order t=2. It can contain a maximum of 2t-1(here, it is 2*2 -1=3) keys in a particular node. But we have assumed the maximum array length to be Key[BTREE_ORDER] which is 2 here. . Is there any other way to do the same or we can just assume the array length to be the maximum ie. 2t-1

Comment: Sorry I got my order the wrong way round - use BTREE_ORDER-1 and BTREE_ORDER